# SQL Query to accept a name and display it with its first character printed five times

Tags: sql, oracle

This Oracle SQL query is meant to accept a name and display it by prefixing itself with its first character 5 times.

```
Select lpad('&name',10,substr('&name',1,1)) Result from dual;
```

Input is:

```
Enter value for name: ORACLE

Enter value for name: ORACLE
```

Result

```
--------
OOOOORACLE
```

However, I do not want to enter the name twice. How can I stop this?

Comment: hi can you share your script again ? because it is giving syntax error

Comment: For a start, the original poster forgot to close the first `&name` with a closing apostrophe, but this isnt why he has to enter the name twice, this is just why you are getting a syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

Use &&

```
Select lpad('&&name',10,substr('&&name',1,1)) Result from dual;
```

Comment: The only problem with this is if you run it again after the initial run (I'm using SQL+), you don't get to redefine your variable - it will be set to the first input until the application closes.

Comment: you can issue command `undef name;` and before executing query second time sqlplus will prompt you for value

Comment: Thanks for your time but my request is to display the substring of given name should be 5times following the name.

Answer (score 0):

You can write this :

```
Select lpad('&name',10,substr('&name',1,1)) Result from dual;
```

it just ask one time and result is `OOOOORACLE`

Oracle version is : ***11gr2***

Comment: Thanks for your time but my request is the substring of given name should be fix for 5 times.